# quantile of higher order

Tags: r, math, statistics, quantile

given a simple dataset in R, I neeed to find out the 40th quantile of it. How can this be done?

```
dataset<-rnorm(50e3)
quantile(dataset, "40th-quantile")
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
quantile(dataset, 0.4)
```